# Difference in Workspace and Simulink step response. Why this difference?

Tags: matlab, simulink, control-theory, pid-controller

I had as primary objective to make a controller for the transfer function (5.551* s^2), using root locus I made the controller shown below. Analyzing the step response in the Workspace using the step () function I had a satisfactory answer but when I try to transfer this answer to Simulink the response behaves differently, at steady state for example I wish to have the smallest possible error as it was obtained in Workspace but in Simulink there is a big error and for some reason at 8 seconds time (Simulink simulation time) there is a "jump" as shown on the display and when I change the simulation time there is a change in this "jump" too and I do not know why these changes between one environment and another.

**Step response in Workspace**
[image: Step response in Workspace]

**Step response in Simulink with 8s of simulation**
[image: Step response in Simulink with 8s of simulation]

**Step response in Simulink with 12s of simulation**
[image: Step response in Simulink with 12s of simulation]

**Simulink controller**
[image: Simulink controller]

**Simulink transfer function**
[image: Simulink transfer function]

I expected to make a controller that has an error less than 5% and an overshoot smaller than 25%, so I first made a controller with two integrators to nullify the effects of zeros on the source, after that I added two more integrators on the source to try decrease the error, the zero at -0.652 I used the angular condition for this and the gain of 0.240251 I used the modular condition.

I wasn't expecting the most optimized behavior possible, just that it has minimum conditions that satisfy the imposed conditions, so I didn't worry for example about the four integrators at the source.

I tried use the sisotool() command thinking that I had done something wrong, but the result changed a lot when I was simulating Simulink so I discarded this option and kept the controller I made using root locus.

Answer (score 1):

Your MATLAB code and your Simulink model are not the same, and hence the different results.

MATLAB allows you to define the non-causal plant model `P_ball`, then form the causal closed loop `CL`, which can have its step response generated.

Simulink does not allow you to model non-causal blocks (even if the overall model is causal) and hence will not allow you to implement `s^2`, which I assume is why you have used two differentiation blocks.  But a numerical differentiation is not the same as a Laplace `s` operator.

You would have to make the plant causal by incorporating two poles that are large enough to not adversely effect the overall simulation.  So your plant model needs to be something like 5.551*s^2/((s/1000 + 1)(s/1000 + 1))  which can be implemented using a `Transfer Function` block with a numerator of 5.551*1000*1000*[1 0 0] and a denominator of [1 2*1000 1000*1000].

Alternatively you could just implement `PID * P_ball` (where you manually do the 2 zero/pole cancellations) which is causal.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented the PID * P_ball and it was right, but i didn't understand the part of " ((s/1000 + 1)(s/1000 + 1)) " because that change my transfer function, I understand that i need make a causal function but there is another way to implement the ideia but separating the controller from the transfer function, in other words, forcing the s^2 ? And do you know why that "jump" in the end of simulation? Thanks you again !

Comment: `s` is non-causal and can't be implemented.  `1000*s/(s+1000)` is causal and can be implemented.  Since their response is (to all intents and purposes) identical up to a relatively high frequency, the later transfer function can be substituted for the former.  The jump at the end is due to your use of a numerical derivative.  It is an artifact of your bad implementation not of the system you are trying to implement.